# bash - find duplicate file in directory and rename

Tags: bash

I have a directory that has thousands of files in it with various extensions.  I also have a drop location where users drop files to be migrated to this directory.  I'm looking for a script that will scan the target directory for a duplicate file name, if found, rename the file in the drop folder, then move it to the target directory.
Example:

/target/file.doc
/drop/file.doc

Script will rename file.doc to file1.doc then move it to /target/.
It needs to maintain the file extension too.

Comment: Are you sure for what you said: *scan the target directory for a duplicate file name, if found, rename the file in the drop folder, then move it to the target directory.* So **what do you mean by duplicate**? You mean duplicate in **name** or in **existence**. Add a more exact example

Answer (score 2):

```
for fil in /drop/* 
do
    test -f "/target/$fil"
    if [ "$?" = 0 ]
    then
        suff=$(awk -F\. '{ print "."$NF }' <<<$fil)
        bdot=$(basename -s $suff $fil)
        mv "/drop/$fil" "/drop/${bdot}1$suff"
        cp "/drop/${bdot}1.$suff" "/target/${bdot}1$suff"
    fi
done
```

Take each file in the drop directory and check it is existing the /target using test -e. If it does then move (rename) and then copy.

Comment: this won't preserve the extension

Comment: Quite right @Kip K. I have amended to take account of the extension,

Answer (score 1):

You have to take a bit more care than simply checking if a file exists before moving in order to provide a flexible solution that can handle files with or without extensions. You also may want to provide a way of forming duplicate filenames that preserves sort order. e.g. if `file.txt` already exists, you may want to use `file_001.txt` as the duplicate in `target` rather than `file1.txt` as when you reach `10` you will no longer have a canonical sort by filename.

Also, you never want to iterate with `for i in $(ls dir)` that is wrought with pitfalls. See [**Bash Pitfalls No. 1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)

Putting those pieces together, and including detail in the comments below, you could do something similar to the following and have a reasonable flexible solution allowing you to specify only the `filename.ext` to move or `/path/to/drop/filename.ext`. You must specify the `drop` and `target` directories in the script to meet your circumstance., e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

tgt=target          ## set target and drop directories as required
drp=drop
declare -i cnt=1    ## counter for filename_$cnt

test -z "$1" && {   ## validate one argument given
    printf "error: insufficient input\nusage: %s filename\n" "${0##*/}"
    exit 1
}
test -w "$1" || test -w "$drp/$1" || {   ## validate valid filename is writeable
    printf "error: file not found or lack permission to move '%s'.\n" "$1"
    exit 1
}

fn="${1##*/}"                   ## strip any path info from filename
if test "$1" != "${1%.*}" ; then
    ext="${fn##*.}"             ## get file extension
    fnwoe="${fn%."$ext"}"       ## get filename without extension
    test "$fnwoe" = '' && ext=  ## was a dotfile, reset ext
fi

vfn="$fn"   ## set valid filename = filename

## form valid filename e.g. "$fn_001.$ext" if duplicate found
while test -e "$tgt/$vfn"; do
    if test -n "$ext"   ## did we have have an extension?
    then
        printf -v vfn "%s_%03d.%s" "$fnwoe" "$((cnt++))" "$ext"
    else
        printf -v vfn "%s_%03d" "$fn" "$((cnt++))"
    fi
done

mv "$drp/$fn" "$tgt/$vfn"       ## move file under non-conflicting name
```

**Example drop and target**

```
$ ls -1 drop
file
file.txt

$ ls -1 target
file.txt
file_001.txt
file_002.txt
```

**Example Use**

```
$ bash mvdrop.sh file
$ bash mvdrop.sh drop/file.txt
```

**Resulting drop and target**

```
$ ls -1 drop

$ ls -1 target
file
file.txt
file_001.txt
file_002.txt
file_003.txt
```

Comment: Don't use `-o`; it's non-standard and all but deprecated. Use `test -w "$1" || test -w "$drp/$1"` instead.

Answer (score -1):

This will test to see if it exists, preserve the extension (along with any structure before the extension such as in the case of FILE.tar.gz), and move it to the target directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET="\target\"
DROP="\drop\"

for F in `ls $DROP`; do
    if [[ -f $TARGET$F ]]; then
        EXT=`echo $F | awk -F "." '{print $NF}'`
        PRE=`echo $F | awk -F "." '{$NF="";print $0}' | sed -e 's/ $//g;s/ /./g'`
        mv $DROP$F $DROP$PRE"1".$EXT
        F=$PRE"1".$EXT
    fi
    mv $DROP$F $TARGET
done
```

Additionally you may want to do come restricting in the `ls` command, so that you aren't copying entire directories.

Display only regular files (no directories or symbolic links)

```
ls -p $DROP | grep -v /
```

Comment: Awesome thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for.